# Enable sqlite FTS Enhanced Query Syntax in python in RHEL6?

Tags: rhel, python, sqlite

SQLite's [full text search engine](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.htm) offers a simple query syntax (with `AND` and `OR` operators and `-term` for negation), as well as an enhanced query syntax which also allows parenthesis and `NEAR` — as well as using `NOT` instead of the `-term` syntax.

The [enhanced query syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_1) is enabled by [setting the SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS option at compile time](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_fts3_parenthesis), and sqlite as distributed by Red Hat does not have this enabled.

I have a python web app where I'd prefer to use the enhanced search syntax.

What's the best way to do this? Since the syntax is incompatible, rebuilding the system sqlite might break other things. But I'd prefer not to end up in a whole world of maintaining a parallel python tree. What's the best approach?